# Bounded operator on a normed space with empty spectrum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

A bounded operator acting on a complex Banach space has non-empty spectrum, and the proof of this fact uses the completeness of the space.

Is there any example of bounded operator acting on a complex non-complete normed space with empty spectrum?

I understand that the spectrum of an operator $T$ is the set of all complex numbers $\lambda$ such that $T-\lambda I$ is not bijective.

Comment: Your clarification of "spectrum" was essential, since every bounded operator on a normed space has an approximate eigenvalue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take an operator on a Banach space whose image is dense, whose spectrum is $\{0\}$ but that has no kernel, for example
$$
T(f)(x)=\int_x^1f(y)dy
$$ 
acting on $H:=L^2([0,1])$.

Then its restriction to the dense subspace $D:=\bigcap_n Im(T^n)$ should have the property you desire.
First of all, $D$ is dense in $H$ -- see the comments below by Alexander Shamov.

Clearly, $T|_D$ is invertible.

So all that remains to be checks is that for $\lambda\not=0$, the operator $(T-\lambda)$ is invertible on $D$. Recall that $(T-\lambda)^{-1}$ makes sense on $H$.
The trick is to note that $(T-\lambda)^{-1}$ preserves $D$. Indeed it preserves each subspace $Im(T^n)$:  If $x\in Im(T^n)$ write it as $x=T^ny$ and then we have  $(T-\lambda)^{-1}x=(T-\lambda)^{-1}T^ny=T^n(T-\lambda)^{-1}y\in Im(T^n)$. QED

Comment: This looks good, but is it obvious that that subspace really is dense?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: $\bigcap_n \mathop{\mathrm{im}} T^n$ is dense iff $\mathop{\mathrm{im}} T$ is dense iff $\ker T^\ast = 0$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: It's actually a general fact that if we have a sequence of spaces $B_0 \supset B_1 \supset B_2 \supset \dots$ that are complete, respectively, w.r.t. norms $\Vert \cdot \Vert_0 \le \Vert \cdot \Vert_1 \le \Vert \cdot \Vert_2 \le \dots$ and all $B_{k+1}$ are dense in $(B_k, \Vert \cdot \Vert_k)$ then $\bigcap_k B_k$ is dense in $B_0$. In this case take the norms $\Vert T^{-k} (\cdot) \Vert$ on $\mathop{\mathrm{im}} T^k$.

Comment: @AlexanderShamov : Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The general fact Alexander is referring to is sometimes called "abstract Mittag-Leffler theorem" (a version of this is e.g. in Bourbaki). The first explicit appearance however is in an article of R. Arens from 1958.

Comment: A version of the result mentioned by Alexander Shamov can be found in Proposition 1.B.1 (page 44) of B. Beauzamy. Introduction to Operator Theory and Invariant Subspaces. North-Holland 1988.