# Empty spectrum of an operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Recently, I was studying the spectrum of an operator $T$ on a normed
linear space $X$. In order to ensure that the spectrum is non-empty, one
needs to assume that $X$ is a complex Banach space. But the books don't give
sufficient justification. I would like to have an example of a real
incomplete normed linear space as well as an example of a complex
incomplete normed linear space $X$ and a bounded operator $T:X \rightarrow X$ such
that the spectrum of $T$ is empty. In order to avoid confusion, I would like
to define the spectrum: A scalar $\lambda$ is called a spectral value of a
bounded operator $T$ on a normed linear space $X$ if $T - \lambda I$ is not
invertible. '$I$' is the identity operator on $X$ and the set of all spectral
values of $T$ is called the spectrum of $T$.

Comment: I don't understand the point about the non-complete example over the real field. Even on the complete real space $\mathbb{R}^2$ there are simple operators with empty spectrum.

Answer (score 2):

I think the example in [Previous question in mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188288/bounded-operator-on-a-normed-space-with-empty-spectrum?rq=1) works both in the real and in the complex case.